# Fluent NHibernate mapping ignore all classes that inherit from generic base class

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a project that has:

```
Repository Project:
[
    Models:
    [
        StudentEntity
        ClassEntity
    ]
    Overrides:
    [
        StudentEntityOverride
        ClassEntityOverride
    ]   

    RepositoryObject
]
```

The RepositoryObject class inherits from a base class of Repo<TEntity, TOverride> When I setup the mappings:

```
AutoMap
.AssemblyOf<TEntity>()               
.UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<TOverride>()
.Conventions.Add(DefaultLazy.Never())
.Conventions.Add(DefaultCascade.SaveUpdate());
```

It will fail as the RepositoryObject will not have an ID mapped.  The Repo base class and the session factory setup and mapping is in a nuget package so not directly changeable.  What I would like to do is be able to set the mappings to ingore any classes that inherit from Repo<TEntity, TOverride>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an exception like this probably:

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<TEntity>().Where(x => x != typeof (Repo<TEntity, TOverride>));
```

Comment: that got me most of the way there.  .Where(x => !x.IsSubclassOf(typeof(Repo<TEntity, TOverride>)))